# Why ever not use SQL Server Express for Windows based application?

Tags: windows, sql-server-express

Considering that SQL Server Express is free, why would you ever use any other database for a Windows based multi-user database-driven application?

Comment: There are plenty of other free database servers which run on Windows - couldn't your question be asked just as easily for them?

Comment: SQL Server Express is great - but it's a *server* and needs to be installed separately - that *can* be a drawback

Comment: @JonSkeet: SQL Server is practically the industry standard for Windows environments. If you can use a free version of that, why would you use anything else?

Comment: @CraigJohnston: There are plenty of possible reasons, each of which could be very specific to the person involved - this just seems a strange question to ask, rather than a less "biased"-sounding question of "Which free database engine should I use for a Windows-based application, and why?" That would probably be closed due to being too open-ended too, but it would at least sound like a more reasonable question IMO. Fundamentally there are many factors which depend on specific requirements.

Comment: Because it doesn't contain unicorns.

Comment: @marc_s: it can be included in deployment packages can't it?  Also, it is a server but isn't that what we want because we don't want the unreliability of a file based DB.

Comment: @CraigJohnston: YES - I would agree - a server is a good thing - but it still does require a separate installation. Not a big deal in my opinion - and well worth the effort!

Comment: @UweKeim I don't know where you got your copy, but mine *does* include the unicorns!

Comment: @AndrewBarber Can you give me the link to your version? I'm keen on unicorns :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because (not sure if all of these are still true, but they were at one time):

- Limited to 1GB of memory
- Database size limited to 4GB (10GB in newer versions)
- It can only use one CPU
- No importing or exporting of data
- No job scheduler

There are a lot of applications for which the above factors make SQL Server Express impractical.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (and SQL Server 2012 Express) lift that database size limit to **10 GB** - and there are free alternative tools for e.g. SQL Server Express Jobs and Profiler and so on

Comment: Fair enough, but the limitation of 1GB of memory and one CPU are still enough to make it impractical for plenty of applications.